# problem with dynamic array and pointers in selection sort

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, pointers, dynamic-arrays

i make a program of selection sort using dynamic array and pointers but after running this code i found that array is being sorted if we give the size input like 4 and 6 but does't sort properly if the size input is like 5 and 7 etc ...i also did bubble sort program before this using same technique of pointers and dynamic array but it gave perfect sorted array in all the condition , i also try to debuge the code but still don't understand why this is happening if anyone having idea about this then please help me out .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int * ptr,temp,min;
  int size,i,j,s;
  printf("Enter the size of array:");
  scanf("%d",&size);

  ptr = (int *)(calloc (size,sizeof(int)));

  if(ptr == NULL)
    printf("No memory");

  else
  {
    printf("\n=== RANDOM ELEMENTS OF ARRAY ===\n");

    for(s=0;s<size;s++)
      *(ptr+s) = rand()%100;

    for(s=0;s<size;s++)
      printf("\nElement [%d]  = %d ",s,*(ptr+s));

// selection sort algorithm

  for(i=0;i< size-1;i++)
  {
    min = i;
    for(j=i+1;j<size;j++)
    {
      if(*(ptr+j) < *(ptr+min))
      {
        min = j;
      }
      temp = *(ptr+i);
      *(ptr+i) = *(ptr+min);
      *(ptr+min) = temp;
    }
  }

// End of algorithm

    printf("\n\n=======  SORTED ELEMENTS  =======\n\n");
      for(s=0;s<size;s++)
        printf("Element [%d]  = %d \n",s,*(ptr+s));


  }

}
```

Comment: Not the core issue, but in `C` this cast is wrong:  `ptr = (int *)(calloc (size,sizeof(int)));`  Use `ptr = calloc (size,sizeof(int));`

Comment: @ryyker. It's unnecessary, not necessarily outright wrong as far as I can tell

Comment: If the original array is `3, 2, 1`, the first iteration of the loop swaps 2 and 3 giving you `2,3,1`.  The next iteration swaps `1` and `3`, but the `1` will never replace the `2`.  Your algorithm is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Selection Sort` algorithm seems to be wrong. You have to replace the element in the current index with the minimum after the inner for loop finishes iteration:

```c
  for(i=0;i< size-1;i++)
  {
    min = i;
    for(j=i+1;j<size;j++)
    {
      if(*(ptr+j) < *(ptr+min))
      {
        min = j;
      }
    }
    temp = *(ptr+i);
    *(ptr+i) = *(ptr+min);
    *(ptr+min) = temp;
  }
```

Now, it should work for all input sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing away a couple of unnecessary confusion factors...

```
*(ptr + index)
```

Is identical to

```
ptr[index]
```

But the second is much easier to read.

Next, in the following section the variable `min` is introduced,

```
  if(*(ptr+j) < *(ptr+min))
  {
       min = j;
  }
```

...but is not necessary for a simple sort.  Just stick with `i` and `j` and the sort will proceed correctly for either even or odd sets of values.  Finally, to eliminate the memory leak, call `free(ptr);` when `ptr` is no longer needed.  Following is a cleaned up version, with corrections.

```
int main(void)//added void
{
  int * ptr,temp/*,min*/;
  int size,i,j,s;
  printf("Enter the size of array:");
  scanf("%d",&size);

  ptr = calloc (size,sizeof(int));//casting is required in C++ 
                                  //but unnecessary in C.
                                  //(and can be problematic)
  if(ptr == NULL)
  {
    printf("No memory");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("\n=== RANDOM ELEMENTS OF ARRAY ===\n");

    for(s=0;s<size;s++)
      ptr[s] = rand()%100;

    for(s=0;s<size;s++)
      printf("\nElement [%d]  = %d ",s,ptr[s]);

// selection sort algorithm

    for(i=0;i< size-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<size;j++)//removed if section introducing 'min'
        {
            if(ptr[j] < ptr[i])
            {
                temp = ptr[i];
                ptr[i] = ptr[j];
                ptr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

// End of algorithm

    printf("\n\n=======  SORTED ELEMENTS  =======\n\n");
    for(s=0;s<size;s++)
        printf("Element [%d]  = %d \n",s,*(ptr+s));

   free(ptr);
  }
  return 0;//added 
}
```

BTW, this was tested with size == 3 and

```
  ptr[0] = 3;
  ptr[1] = 2;
  ptr[2] = 1;
```

along with several other odd and even counts of random values